# How could I pass StateObject to both main struct and AppDelegate(or just AppDelegate)?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, google-oauth, appkit

I began to learn Swift four days ago and I met a problem.

```swift
@main
struct GmailNotificationApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate
    @StateObject var authViewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authViewModel)           // <-----first place
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    private var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    private var popover: NSPopover!
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let statusButton = statusItem.button {
            statusButton.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "g.circle.fill", accessibilityDescription: "Gmail Notification")
            statusButton.action = #selector(togglePopover)
        }
        
        self.popover = NSPopover()
        self.popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 210, height: 300)
        self.popover.behavior = .transient
        self.popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView().environmentObject(AuthenticationViewModel()))    // <-----second place
    }
    
    @objc func togglePopover(){
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            if popover.isShown {
                self.popover.performClose(nil)
            } else {
                self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How could I pass StateObject inside AppDelegate?

Also:

I knew little about AppKit, it seems I have two "window", one is displayed just below menu bar and another shows when Google Auth calls back.

I wish the windows in the center of my screen never shows.
Now I use

```swift
NSApplication.shared.windows.first?.close()
                    
var window: NSWindow!
window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0),
    styleMask: [.borderless],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.center()
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

to work around.
But I think it's very stupid.
So is there a way to `never` show the window in the screen center and just show the windows below menu bar?
I'm quite new to Swift/SwiftUI/AppKit and sorry for these dumb questions.

Comment: you can define `AppDelegate` inside your `GmailNotificationApp` !

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you don't give SwiftUI an instance of your `AppDelegate`. You only give it the **class** object, `AppDelegate.self`, and SwiftUI creates the instance once and keeps it around forever.

I think a better pattern is to create the `AuthenticationViewModel` in your `AppDelegate`. Then you don't need to use `@StateObject` to keep the model alive, because the app delegate will do that. So you can just use `@ObservedObject`:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let authViewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()

    // blah blah blah
}

@main
struct MacStudyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    @ObservedObject private var authViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel

    init() {
        authViewModel = _appDelegate.wrappedValue.authViewModel
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

But in your case, you don't even need to use `@ObservedObject` because `MacStudyApp` doesn't use any properties of `authViewModel` in its body. So you could in fact just do this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let authViewModel = AuthenticationViewModel()

    // blah blah blah
}

@main
struct MacStudyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor private var appDelegate: AppDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appDelegate.authViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I finally solved this problem from your answer! Can I add your Discord? I learned Swift only a few days and sometimes I really confused how to learn this. I won't bother you, but if I met some problems I really can't solve I hope you can give me some advices.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't have a discord. If you have problems you can't solve, that's what Stack Overflow is for. If my answer solved your problem, the best way to thank me is to click the check mark next to it.